# Sorting a list having pairs without comma by first element in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, key-value

I have a list that looks like below:

list = ['8 4', '4 3', '15 8', '10 5', '']

I want to sort this by the first element of each pair in descending order. That is, my output should look like the below.

sortedlist = ['15 8', '8 4', '10 5', '4 3' '']

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is this descending order? `sortedlist = ['15 8', '8 4', '10 5', '4 3' '']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` and use first element of each pair.

```
lst  = ['8 4', '4 3', '15 8', '10 5', '']


def key_sort(x):
    try:
        return int(x.split()[0]) # '8 4'.split() -> ['8', '4']
    except IndexError:
        # for handling empty string : `''`
        return float('-inf')

lst.sort(key=key_sort, reverse = True)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['15 8', '10 5', '8 4', '4 3', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:  (use the helper *sort_key)*

L = ['8 4', '4 3', '15 8', '10 5']

```py
def sort_key(x):
    tp = x.split()
    return -(int(tp[0]))   #, int(tp[1])  <--- updated based on feedback

>>>sorted(L, key=sort_key)
['15 8', '10 5', '8 4', '4 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
lst  = ['8 4', '4 3', '15 8', '10 5', '']
```

Try:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]) if len(x) else float("-inf"), reverse = True)
```

outputs:

```
['15 8', '10 5', '8 4', '4 3', '']
```

Comment: How do you handle this : `lst  = ['8 4', '4 3', '15 8', '10 5', '', ' ', '    ']`

Comment: As it is, it doesn't

Comment: This works, thanks.! I did try sorted earlier, but did not include the 'If' part and it always resulted in an 'index out of range' error.